# Azure Virtual Machine / Windows Server 2012 and "This web page is not available" error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have just created an azure virtual server 2012 and made a simple html page.
I installed IIS on it, and added an endpoint to my portal, called it web and set it to tsp, 80, 80, no load balanced.

But when I try to go to my domain, I get an error saying page not available.
I can login to my virtual server and run the page inside. So it works. 
But it's blocking outside access.

There is also a firewall rule on the server allowing incoming traffic on port 80.

I am probably missing a step somewhere, but I could not find any instructions on how to do it. It is mostly guess work on my side.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have forgotten to allow port 80 for incoming connection on the local Firewall of your Windows Server.

**UPDATE**

Have you correctly mapped "your domain" to the couldapp.net domain of the VM instance? Or are you using the yourname.cloudapp.net directly?

Comment: I had the rule already. After your answer i tried it by allowing all traffic in on the firewall just in case i did the rule wrong, but it still does not work. Same error

Comment: Yes, that's it, there was a typo in my IP within the domain mapping. Should have tried using the cloudapp.net to test. Hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks. That sorted it, i tested it now with the cloudapp.net so that i would not have to wait for the dns to update. And it works.

Comment: great what helped me here is to let me know I also need to add a HTTP endpoint to the VM server so that it can then use the ???. couldapp.net and any donain signed to it. thanks